# PHP validate string only contains '0-9', '.', '*', '/', '-', '+' for a calculator?

Tags: php, if-statement, while-loop, preg-match, calculator

Im trying to write code for a php calculator that evaluates from left to write in order of operation simple statements like:

```
$equation = '5.2 + 3.36 * 0.80';
while(!is_Numeric($equation))
{
   //perform operation
}
```

But if someone types a value that is not one of  `'0-9', '.', '*', '/', '-', '+'` the `while` statement will never exit. An `if(preg_match())` before the `while` will do the trick but I'm not very familiar with how to use it

Comment: At the very least, include the code you are having issues with. Without it, nobody will be able to help you...

Comment: Be careful with your validation.  Just because it only contains those characters doesn't mean it's a valid equation.  For example, the following is "valid": `1.2.3.4 */* - / 0`

Answer (score 2):

Use this regular expression

```
if (preg_match('~^[0-9.*/+-]+$~', $str)) {
    // ...
}
```

[You don't need to escape other characters than `\, -, ^, ]` and the delimiter in character classes](http://php.net/manual/de/regexp.reference.character-classes.php) and you can also avoid escaping most of these.

Answer (score 1):

PCRE is very convenient way to check if string contains only the given characters

```
if (preg_match('/^([0-9\.\*\/\-\+])+$/', $string)) { ...
```

You should just pass the charset between `[` and `]` (escaping any special characters), tell that you want 1 or more characters, and also tell that it has to start and end with the charset, which means that the entire string should match the expression (otherwise you will match part of the string)

Comment: I think the comma after 0-9 shouldn't be there.

Comment: @steffen the comma is in the original charset as posted by OP